# How to compile the Botan crypto library as a static lib in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cryptography, botan

I've been extremely unsuccessful in compiling Botan as a static library in Visual C++. The build.h file contains the following code:

```
#ifndef BOTAN_DLL
  #define BOTAN_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
```

This macro then shows up pretty much everywhere in the Botan codebase, like this:

```
class BOTAN_DLL AutoSeeded_RNG : public RandomNumberGenerator
```

My understanding from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991842/how-to-link-a-static-library-in-visual-c-2008) is that all you need to do is define BOTAN_DLL without a value and it should compile as a static library just fine. However, doing so causes a huge list of build errors like "missing tag name." Anyone know how to do this?

**EDIT**: Here is a sample of the errors that result from adding /D "BOTAN_DLL" to the makefile:

```
        cl.exe /Ibuild\include /O2  /EHsc /GR /D_CONSOLE /D "BOTAN_DLL"  /nologo
 /c src\checksum\adler32\adler32.cpp /Fobuild\lib\adler32.obj
adler32.cpp
build\include\botan/allocate.h(19) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
build\include\botan/allocate.h(19) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' bef
ore 'constant'
build\include\botan/allocate.h(19) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
build\include\botan/allocate.h(20) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' bef
ore '{'
build\include\botan/allocate.h(20) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header
(old-style formal list?)
build\include\botan/secmem.h(229) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' befo
re '*'
        build\include\botan/secmem.h(230) : see reference to class template inst
antiation 'Botan::MemoryRegion<T>' being compiled
build\include\botan/secmem.h(229) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int as
sumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: Could you please quote some source that fails to compile with BOTAN_DLL defined as empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the first few error messages you get? Maybe you have forgotten a header file include?

It looks like maybe your compilation command is wrong:

```
cl.exe /Ibuild\include /O2  /EHsc /GR /D_CONSOLE /D "BOTAN_DLL"  /nologo
 /c src\checksum\adler32\adler32.cpp /Fobuild\lib\adler32.obj
```

I think you incorrectly have a space between the `/D` [directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx) and the value of the preprocessor symbol you are defining. It should be this:

```
cl.exe /Ibuild\include /O2  /EHsc /GR /D_CONSOLE /DBOTAN_DLL=  /nologo
 /c src\checksum\adler32\adler32.cpp /Fobuild\lib\adler32.obj
```

EDIT: if you have `/DBOTAN_DLL`, this is equivalent to `/DBOTAN_DLL=1`, you want to use `/DBOTAN_DLL=` which will give it no associated value. With this `/DBOTAN_DLL`, it is inserted into your code as the value 1, and the compiler sees the error:

```
class 1 Allocator { ...
```

Comment: What is on line 19 of allocate.h here? build\include\botan/allocate.h(19) : error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name

Comment: It's simply the class definition, like in the original post:

class BOTAN_DLL Allocator

Comment: It doesn't appear to make a difference whether I put /D "BOTAN_DLL" or /DBOTAN_DLL, the same list of errors comes up.

Comment: Sorry yes I made a mistake - you need to have /DBOTAN_DLL= (note the "=" symbol)

Comment: Thanks, it compiled this time but do I need to add this preprocessor definition to the project in VC++ that is using the library? Simply adding "#define BOTAN_DLL" in that project doesn't seem to work.

Comment: For example, I get a lot of warnings about such and such "needs to have dll-interface".

Comment: Roughly speaking, if you are wanting to use the library static linked, then the "dllexport" and "dllimport" directives should not be used at all - so you really need to make sure that symbol is defined correctly so that the directive is not applied

Comment: Right, I fixed that problem by adding /DBOTAN_DLL= to my VC++ project as well. Those warnings no longer appear, but the compile still fails with 62 errors, mainly syntax errors in the botan header files, such as: dl_group.h(51): error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before '('.

Comment: Line 51 in that file, by the way, is simply a line in the following enumeration: enum Format {
         ANSI_X9_42,
         ANSI_X9_57,
         PKCS_3,

         DSA_PARAMETERS = ANSI_X9_57,
         DH_PARAMETERS = ANSI_X9_42,
         X942_DH_PARAMETERS = ANSI_X9_42,
         PKCS3_DH_PARAMETERS = PKCS_3
      };

Comment: Sometimes the error is caused by an error flowing over from the previous line, what is on the previous line?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, here is the file: http://files.randombit.net/botan/doxygen/html/dl__group_8h-source.html

Comment: I can't see anything obvious wrong with that file. Is the line 51 the first error in the output?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't think there is actually is a syntax error, as this library is widely used. I think something else is causing it to show up. Here is all of my output: http://pastebin.com/m52ec634

Comment: My guess is you have some other preprocessor symbols which are interfering with the build. I would add the /P (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6(VS.80).aspx) command line option to your build - this means that the compiler will output the full preprocessed output to a file with the same name but ending in ".i" - you can then open that file and see what the file looks like around the bit that is causing the error

Answer (score 4):

I recently had the need to build a static Botan library myself, and though this is a rather old thread, I thought I would post an answer. I believe the "intended" way to do this is using a configuration option. If you specify

```
configure.py --disable-shared
```

then the generated makefile builds a static botan.lib instead of a .dll. It also generates build.h containing

```
#ifndef BOTAN_DLL
  #define BOTAN_DLL 
#endif
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

__declspec(dllexport) doesn't have anything to do with compiling as a static library. It just signals linker to export specific functionality. To instruct linker to build a static library you must specify Static Library (lib) in

Configuration Type | General | Configuration Type

in project properties dialog. If this particular configuration builds as a dll change of configuration type is not supposed to cause errors.

Comment: I'm not actually building the library in VC++; it's build process is too complex for that. I am building it with nmake using the makefile generated by Botan's configure.pl, then attempting to link my VC++ project to it.